# JSNI from native element attribute in GWT UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder, jsni

Is it possible to bind event-handling attributes of native elements to widget methods?

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <div onclick="{???}">Hello</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

For example, in `MyWidget.ui.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM 'http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent'>
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' 
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
  <ui:style>
  </ui:style>

  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <div onclick="myFunction()"> DIV EXAMPLE </div>
  </g:HTMLPanel>  

</ui:UiBinder>
```

and for example in your `html`, you introduce (for example inside the `<head>` tag):

```
<script> 
    function myFunction() {
      alert("Bye");
    }
  </script>
```

and in your `GWT`'s `EntryPoint`:

```
public class ExampleGWT implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    MyWidget m = new MyWidget();
    RootPanel.get().add(m);
  }

}
```

You'll be able to see **"Bye" alert**.

I imagine that you have your reasons for doing it, but under my opinion it is not the best way of using GWT ((you can not debug, you missed the GWT' compiler optimizations, you can not take advantage of UiBinder and Composite properly...).

If you give us more details about your scenario maybe we can point you in a better direction (there are tools like GQuery, which allows you bind events really fast without boilerplate code for example).

Thanks!

Comment: I can come up with a workaround, but it is kinda cumbersome. Plus you need to deal with several instances of your widget, so suddenly you have to pass some sort of token or unique name for your JS method. :(